# boundedness of inverse (Evans PDE)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

First, I have difficulty understanding why
$$\|u_k\|_{L^2(U)}>k\|f_k\|_{L^2(U)}$$ is being assumed in theorem 6 chapter 6.2 Evans.

Second, the last sentence of the proof says (30) implies $\|u\|_{L^2(U)}=1.$ Why?

Third, $f_k\to 0$ in $L^2(U).$ Why?
Any clarification is appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It is a proof by contradiction. The first words of the first line of the proof says "if not". This means, "suppose that the estimate (29) is not true". But this means that the reverse inequality is assumed to be true, i.e. $||u_k||_{L^2(U)}>C||f_k||_{L^2(U)}$ for any constant $C$. And constants $k$ are selected for the sake of the arguments stated in the rest of the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show:

> There is $C>0$ so that 
>   $$\|u\|_{L^2(U)} \le C \| f\|_{L^2(U)}$$
>   for all $u \in H^1(U), f\in L^2(U)$ which satisfy the equation (weakly).

In the book, the author argue by contradiction, assuming that the statement is false. Thus:

> For all $C>0$, there is  $u \in H^1(U), f\in L^2(U)$ which satisfy the equation (weakly) and 
>   $$\|u\|_{L^2(U)} > C \| f\|_{L^2(U)}. $$

Of course $u,f$ might depends on $C$. Since it's true for all $C$, by choosing $C = k, k\in \mathbb N$, you come up with $u_k, f_k$ as stated in the book.

Comment: @ John Ma or anyone.   I edited my question. Could you help my 2nd question?

Comment: That's because one can choose $(\frac{u}{c}, \frac fc)$ instead of $(u,f)$ as your equation is still satisfied (since it's linear). Thus choosing $c = \| u_k\|$ for each $k$, you can assume that $\| u\|_{L^2(U)} = 1$. @math101

Comment: Ok. I've heard of this trick but explicitly why lost me a bit. Moreover, a 3rd question added about $f_k.$

Comment: @math101 that follows from $1= \| u_k\|_{L^2(U)} > k \|f_k\|_{L^2(U)}$.